# Converting DiscordUser to DiscordMember

Tags: c#, discord, dsharp+

i have a problem with dsharp+, so basically when i attach an event
`Client.VoiceStateUpdated += OnVoiceState;`

```
private Task OnVoiceState(DiscordClient sender, VoiceStateUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            var member = (DiscordMember) e.After.User;
            Console.WriteLine(member.Nickname);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

and try to convert it from `DiscordUser` to `DiscordMember` it throws an exception, i know that i can do this from docs
[image: DocsDiscordUser]

```
[Error] Exception occured
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'DSharpPlus.Entities.DiscordUser' to type 'DSharpPlus.Entities.DiscordMember'.
   at dcBot.Run.Bot.OnVoiceState(DiscordClient sender, VoiceStateUpdateEventArgs e) in C:\Users\lukas\RiderProjects\discord\bot\Run\Main.cs:line 219
   at Emzi0767.Utilities.AsyncEvent`2.InvokeAsync(TSender sender, TArgs e, AsyncEventExceptionMode exceptionMode)
```

It's working 50% of the time, when i join a channel or leave it throws, but when my friend join a channel it doesn't. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i managed it to work i needed to add this in `DiscordConfiguration`:
`Intents = DiscordIntents.All`
And enable these 2 checks in discord developer:
[image: Checks discord]

Answer (score 1):

I would comment but I don't have enough reputation to do so:

I was able to reproduce the same behaviour myself, I'd suggest opening an issue on the GitHub repository. I'd imagine this being an issue on their part, and if not, they have better knowledge of the expected behaviours and methods.

Hope this helps in the long run.